# Let Dokan / MulitvendorX vendors set currency per product. Best approach?

Tags: plugins, css

Got a question that I'm hoping the community can help me out on.

I want to start a multivender e-commerce site, focusing on American and Japanese customers.  I need to let vendors set prices in their own currency, either yen or dollars.  A simple currency switcher won't do the job, since, if, for example, an American seller has to set convert his dollar to yen to post on my site, the difference between the yen and dollar might change, which could lose (or gain) him money.

I actually almost found a solution, I think.  Booster has this feature and it works great.  It keeps the stores default currency the same (yen in my case) and instead adds an extra USD field and a yen field.  Here, you can set an unchanging price in either currency.  When a customer selects the currency they want to use, rather than use the daily conversion rate, it will use the  set currency if you filled one in.  My US sellers can set a dollar amount and it won't change over time based on the conversion.

The only problem is that I need to let *vendors* input it.  I know there are a couple of ways to do custom fields, such as the ACF plugin which lets me add a custom field to the vendor's add product page.  I can't seem to figure out how to connect the vendor's answer on the add product page to the actual metadata that the Booster plugin uses, if that's even possible.  I figured that, if the USD and yen fields where housed with the rest of a products data, I could just somehow get the ACF to push the data into that data field and viola!

So here's the question.  Is this the best approach?  Is it even a reasonable approach?

Have an idea of a better way to make this work?

In any case, thank you very much for taking the time to read this!  I greatly appreciate it!

Andy